# How to force Google Autocomplete to result in "native language"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Good evening together, I am using the Google Maps API for JavaScript coding. In fact, it's bascically this function: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-addressform?hl=de

Now the question is: if I load the Google Maps in "French" for a French user, it will give me "Cologne" as result for "Köln". How can I force Google to give me the "native" name of each city as result, so Köln for Cologne, Beijing instead of Peking, Pekin, etc.?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try using the language parameter in your script?

```
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&sensor=false&language=yourLanguage"></script>
```

You can see a list of languages here: https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#languagesupport

Comment: Yes, the thing is, the user shall still see "his" language and name of the autosuggest, but when "entering" it in the fields, it shall give the local name. 

If Google Maps is in English and somebody types in "Köln" for Cologne, it will still save "Cologne". How to force to make it "Köln", no matter if entered "Cologne" or "Köln"? So Google Maps = Language of User -> but Results -> Language of Native.